# Problem with HttpHandlers in a asp.net 4 integrated mode hosted at arvixe.com

Tags: .net-4.0, httphandler

I'd like to know if someone has experienced some issues with HttpHandlers at Arvixe hosting provider.

I have set my web site running in asp.net 4 integrated mode, httphandlers are set correctly into the web.config and they work in my windows 7 IIS7 pc.

On the hosting space the httphandlers don't seem to work.

Maybe someone has custom httphandlers working in .net 4 on arvixe?
If so, can I know how you set them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and found that is needed to add handler registration to system.webServer. Something like this:

```
<handlers>

<add name=".jpg" path="*.jpg" verb="GET" type="ImageHandler.HttpImageHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />

</handlers>
```

Hope it will help (if not too late ;-)).